# AngularJS: add/destroy detail table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an Angular 1.4.12 app, with a table created with nested `ng-repeat` showing a set of data.

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in pmt.table.data">
  ...main data...
</tr>
<tr class="table-details" ng-repeat-end="item in pmt.table.data">
    <td colspan="15">
      <div uib-collapse="!item.showDetails">
         <div class="table-details-content">hello world</div>
      </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Each row has a disclosure icon to show an additional row that contains details.

In the past, we have loaded all the data and used Angular UI Bootstrap's "collapse" directive to hide and show the detail rows.

You can see the entire thing in this Pen: https://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/kXpqPJ?editors=1010

The problem with this approach has become apparent when the recordset has a lot of data; such as 1000 rows of json data.  Despite using one-way binding, the performance is too slow.

What I'd rather do is to **not** have the detail rows included at all, and then when the disclosure icon is clicked, *create the row on the fly* and fetch its data based on the parent row ID.  When the disclosure icon is closed, destroy the detail row.

I have done things like this with jQuery, but I'm a bit lost on how to approach with Angular.

Comment: What have you tried? First of all, you'd need a service client to retrieve detail given an ID, then everything else would be interface work. Which one are you stuck at?

Comment: use ng-if to decide which rows not to digest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-if.

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Note that `ng-if` totally creates (and destroys) a new scope - which is what you want, but you would want to pay extra attention to your scope inheritance should you need  the data binding again.

```
      <td colspan="15">
        <!--Change uib-collapse to ng-if-->
        <div ng-if="item.showDetails">
          <div class="table-details-content">hello world</div>
        </div>
      </td>
```

Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cozyazure/pen/rLKRXP?editors=1010#anon-login)

Comment: That's a better solution than the uib-collapse method.  However, with 1000 rows the the load performance is still too slow.  The script part in the timeline, even for local data is over 5 seconds.

Comment: I see. For now, `ng-if` is the closest solution where you can create and destroy DOM elements on the fly. Too bad it is still laggy for you :( Maybe you should move to ng2 where they claim it is at least 4x faster :D Anyway, the overall optimum number of watchers on a browser will be around 2k, probably you can look at other place of your code to see if you can further optimize it?